# A large number of data reads in the Firestore + Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem using the SDK in Unity.
A little bit about of my Firestore: In my game there is a basic collection of users, in each subdocument of which there is a progress collection, and then the numbers of documents with the player's progress.
The problem: I almost don't allow players to read data from the database just to write, but when I want to change something in their data (give them access to testing), then I throw them this opportunity through another service, but for some reason, instead of two document reads, 150 to 600 reads occur. This is a lot and I don't understand why it is. Does anyone know?
Here is a screenshot from Firestore Usage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn63V.png)
Here is my code to read the data:

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> GetDocSnapshotAsync(string collection, string doc)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var getCompleted = false;
        var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection(collection).Document(doc);
        documentReference.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result.Exists)
            {
                result = task.Result.ToDictionary();
            }

            getCompleted = true;
        });
        while (!getCompleted)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> GetSubDocSnapshotAsync(string collection, string doc, string subCollection, string subDoc)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var getCompleted = false;
        var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection(collection).Document(doc).Collection(subCollection).Document(subDoc);
        documentReference.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.Result.Exists)
            {
                result = task.Result.ToDictionary();
            }

            getCompleted = true;
                
        });
        while (!getCompleted)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I tried to perform normal writes and reads without touching inside the Firestore and they worked fine. However, when I change the data inside the Firestore manually, and not through the code, the reading happens randomly or not the number of times, but it is always different.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Aside from that, keep in mind that any data shown in the Firestore console also has to be read from the database and counts towards charged document reads. Even if just the document ID is showing, that is still a charged document read.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen First, I corrected the images to the sample code. 
Secondly, I don't quite understand then why there is a different number of data reads each time.

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from Firebase support. I hope Moises won't mind if I forward it here :)

> This seems related to your interaction with the Firestore console.
> When viewing Firestore collections through the Firebase Console, the first 300 documents in a collection are loaded automatically every time a different collection in the console is selected. When scrolling down a long list of documents, the next 300 documents will be loaded if there are more documents in the collection to display.
> It's generally recommended to be careful when it comes to usage through the Firebase Console. Frequent switching between the Usage tab and the Data tab could rack up a huge amount of read operations. Be mindful.